# Default project dependency disposing inconsistency

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

After creating a new ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio 2017 we get 2 controllers: `AccountController` and `ManageController`. Both controllers use dependency injection via constructors to get `ApplicationSignInManager` and `ApplicationUserManager`.

`AccountController`'s `Dispose`:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (_userManager != null)
        {
            _userManager.Dispose();
            _userManager = null;
        }

        if (_signInManager != null)
        {
            _signInManager.Dispose();
            _signInManager = null;
        }
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

`ManageController`'s `Dispose`:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && _userManager != null)
    {
        _userManager.Dispose();
        _userManager = null;
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Why doesn't `ManageController` dispose sign in manager? Why is it different than `AccountController`?

Comment: Interesting question. I was able to duplicate. My educated guess would be two different developers.What's more interesting is that `ApplicationSignInManager` depends on `ApplicationUserManager` so if anything, this would leave it in an inconsistent state (assuming it's the same object). Either way. I don't like this disposing methodology as I think the scope/lifetime of the object should be controlled by whoever has knowledge of it's instantiation, in this case, the IoC container (the interdependency mentioned above is the very reason why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Juan's comment:

It looks like an oversight, however it doesn't matter because the IoC container should dispose all dependencies so it's fine to even remove the Dispose methods altogether.